# dataframe to correlation matrix

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have a data frame in R (df) which looks like this:

```
colA colB
A,B   0.5
A,C   8
B,A   0.5
B,C   9
C,A   8
C,B   9
```

It represents correlation values obtained by running a certain software.
Now, I would like to convert this data frame to a correlation matrix to be plotted with the Corr() function:

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
   A    B    C 

A  1    0.5  8

B  0.5   1   9

C  8     9    1
```

Please, any suggestion about the code I can utilise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data:

```
input <- structure(list(colA = c("A,B", "A,C", "B,A", "B,C", "C,A", "C,B"
), colB = c(0.5, 8, 0.5, 9, 8, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Solution:

```
## separate that column "colA" into 2
rc <- read.csv(text = input$colA, header = FALSE)
#  V1 V2
#1  A  B
#2  A  C
#3  B  A
#4  B  C
#5  C  A
#6  C  B

tapply(input$colB, unname(rc), FUN = identity, default = 1)
#    A   B C
#A 1.0 0.5 8
#B 0.5 1.0 9
#C 8.0 9.0 1
```

**Note 1:** OP has carelessly made-up data. Correlation is never bigger than 1.

**Note 2:** Thanks [thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803) for suggesting simply using `read.csv` instead of `scan` + `matrix` + `asplit`, as was in [my initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73189279/2).

---

**Remark 1:** If using `xtabs`, we have to modify diagonal elements to 1 later.

**Remark 2:** Matrix indexing is also a good approach, but takes more lines of code.

**Remark 3:** "reshaping" solution is also a good idea.

```
rc$value <- input$colB
reshape2::acast(rc, V1 ~ V2, fill = 1)
#    A   B C
#A 1.0 0.5 8
#B 0.5 1.0 9
#C 8.0 9.0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
# create your input df:
df<-data.frame(colA=c("A,B","A,C","B,A","B,C","C,A","C,B"),value=c(0.5,8,0.5,9,8,9))

# split ID column
df[,c("col.A","col.B")]<- matrix(ncol=2,unlist(strsplit(df$colA,",")),byrow = T)
# reshape
library(reshape2)
dcast( df , col.A~col.B ,fill=1)
```